# Change the color of an inputdlg field name

Tags: matlab, dialog, customization, matlab-gui, text-coloring

This is my code:

```matlab
classDefault={'','','','',''};
fieldNames= {'Class Number','Class Name'};
title='Enter Class Information';
numlines=1;  
y =inputdlg(fieldNames,title,numlines,classDefault);
```

it shows:

[image]

I want to change the color of the field name, like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`tex` interpreter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html#d122e663519):

```matlab
function q65234922()
classDefault = {'','','','',''};
fieldNames = {'\color{red}Class Number','Class Name'};     % Change 1
title = 'Enter Class Information';
numlines = 1;
opts = struct('Interpreter','tex');                        % Change 2
y = inputdlg(fieldNames,title,numlines,classDefault,opts); % Change 3
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! 
this was really helpful